# Facebook App Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException:

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

First I authenticate the user and get permissions on index.php and after authenticating the user is redirected to action.php where the app does its work.

I get this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be
>   used to query information about the current user. thrown in
>   /home/flysw4fr/public_html/event/facebook.php

This app worked fine two years ago and now it no longer works

here is my code for action.php

```
    <?php

require_once('config.php');

if(!$_SESSION['init']){
    die;
}

unset($_SESSION['init']);

require_once('facebook.php');

$data = loaddata();
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbappid,
  'secret' => $appsecret,
  'cookie' => true,
));



$friendsdate = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
if($friendsdate && $friendsdate['data'] && count($friendsdate['data'])){
    $friends = array();
    foreach($friendsdate['data'] as $f){
        $friends[] = $f['id'];
    }

    sleep(3);

    $session = $facebook->getSession();
    $params = array('name' => $data['name'], 
                     'start_time' => $data['start_time'], 
                     'end_time' => $data['end_time'],
                     'description' => $data['description']);
    if($data['source']){
        $params['source'] = '@'.realpath('image/'.$data['source']);
        $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
    }
    $result = $facebook->api('/me/events', 'POST', $params);

    sleep(4);
    $eid = $result['id'];

    $params = array(
        'access_token' => $facebook-> getAccessToken(),
        'eid' =>$eid,
        'api_key' => $fbappid,
        'uids'=> implode(',', $friends),
        'format'=>'json-strings',
        'personal_message'=> $data['personal_message']
    );

    $url = 'https://api.facebook.com/method/events.invite';
    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(false);
    $result = $facebook->makeRequest($url, $params);
}

header('Location: '.$data['url']);
```

Comment: Facebook::getSession is outdated. Get a current version of the SDK, and adapt your code to it.

Comment: "*This app worked fine **two years ago** and now it no longer works*".

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously update your code and use the current SDK version or you can use opengraph.

Facebook::getSession is outdated now, which wasnt, 2 years before. (This app worked fine two years ago and now it no longer works :-/)